# Unable to connect to adapter

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, mobilefirst-adapters

I have following code called when loading the page:

```
var resourceRequest = new WLResourceRequest(
    "adapters/adapter-name/rest/init/" + timeStamp,
    WLResourceRequest.GET
);
```

However it returns error in my console:

> GET http://localhost:10080/project-name/adapters/adapter-name/rest/init/0 404
>   (Not Found)

While this code works:

```
function wlEnvInit() {       
    console.log("CONNECTING 1111");
    WL.Client.connect({c
        onSuccess: function(){
           console.log("CONNECTED 2222");
        },
        onFailure: function(error) {
            console.log("ERROR IN CONNECTION");
            console.log(error);
        }
    });
}
```

How to troubleshoot this?

Comment: The former has nothing to do with the latter... It'd be better if you will provide your adapter implementation.

Comment: hi Idan, thanks. But this one should not related to adapter implementation, since it's 404 not found. Can I base on `WL.Client.connect`? If it's success means that my app can connect to mfp server successfully?

Comment: The errors likely means that either the adapter is not there, or your endpoint is not there (i.e you're not using resource request correctly, which is why I want you to supply the adapter implementation as well). It'll also help if you'll mention what is your MobileFirst version since there are several.

Answer (score 0):

1. Make sure the adapter is really deployed by visiting the console
2. Make sure that your application is pointing to an IP address of the host machine where the MobileFirst Server is deployed to
3. Make sure your adapter call is correct

Example calling:

- Client side:https://github.com/MobileFirst-Platform-Developer-Center/ResourceRequestCordova/blob/release80/www/js/index.js#L54
- Server side: https://github.com/MobileFirst-Platform-Developer-Center/Adapters/blob/release80/JavaAdapter/src/main/java/com/sample/adapter/JavaAdapterResource.java#L25

Comment: #1 is correct. For others I will try to troubleshoot from adapter level. Thanks Idan! :)